# R and HTML connectivity

Tags: java, html, r

I am a complete noob in R and Java. What I need to do is connect HTML and R in such a way that user inputs a certain query or keyword in HTML form and then that keyword is sent to R for processing.

After the processing is done, I should be able to see the output in HTML. I have read that Java servlets can do the job but could not find anything that could help me.

Comment: you are looking for `shiny` search for it

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at Shiny for R, it should allow you to fairly quickly build a small web front end around your R script, including user inputs as parameters/filters for the script.

Answer (score 0):

A library like Jupyter might help you.  It's a combination of R, Python and Javascript.  jupyter.org

Writing a servlet means you do all the coding yourself to output strings that contain the HTML.  Web programmers do this all the time.  We wouldn't ask that as a question.  So, I suggest a library instead, as it will requireless skill to implement.